# Turn off auto parentheses creation in code::blocks

Tags: autocomplete, codeblocks, parentheses

If I type

```
UTF
```

and then select the function autocomplete comes up with, I get

```
UTF8Encode()
```

What I'd like to end up with is

```
UTF8Encode
```

So I don't end up with

```
UTF8Encode();)
```

Answer (score 0):

Editor -> Code completition -> (main tab code completition) -> and you need to deselect 
"Add paranthese after function name auto complete"